# Why does spring batch's MongoItemWriter not use org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.BulkOperations?

Tags: spring-batch

I would think it would perform much better. Is there some guarantee I'd lose using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why it could not use bulk operations. Feel free to open an issue and contribute the improvement if you want.

> Is there some guarantee I'd lose using that?

No, you should have the same results.

Comment: Some minor history...the reason `MongoItemWriter` doesn't use `BulkOperations` is because it didn't exist yet when the writer was created.  `BulkOperations` was added in Spring Data Mongo 1.9.  The writer was originally created against Spring Data Mongo 1.1.  This feels like a good enhancement IMHO.